# XNA Debugging freezes Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xna

When I try to run my XNA game in Visual Studio 2012, it freezes. When I try to kill it with taskmgr, Visual Studio window disappears, but the process is still there and when I try to kill it, it does nothing. My XNA game is in the process list too and it's same as devenv.exe (I can't kill it). When I restart my PC all devenv and my XNA game processes are not running of course. I tried switching between Reach and HiDef, Debug and Release, but still same.

Please help me whit this issue.

Comment: At what point during debugging it freezes? Did you try a blank XNA project? please note that VS2012 is not officially supported for XNA development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that you have Avast Antivirus. It may be that Avast DeepScreen is quarantining your game as soon as it begins running, causing Visual Studio to freeze.

Instead of disabling DeepScreen, go into the Avast settings and add your project into the file path exclusions. That should let Avast know not to bother you.